# Creating an efficient early instance clip WebGL2 vertext shader

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, webgl2

### Discarding instances in the vertex shader

I am using instanced geom to display content using webGL2. As part of the process each instance has a color component which for some instances may have an alpha value of zero.

Rather than have it passed on to the fragment shader to discard, I check alpha in the vertext shader. If zero then I output each vert as `vec4(-2)` to put it outside the clip or at worst have it as a 1 pixel point.

I can not find information on how this is handled by the rendering pipe.

Is this the best strategy to remove instances from the pipeline?

The alternative is to remove the instances from the buffer which in JS is a CPU intensive operation when dealing with 1000's of instances.

### The shaders

```
const vertexSrc = `#version 300 es
    #define alphaCut 0.0
    in vec2 verts;
    in vec2 pos;       
    in vec2 scale;     
    in vec2 offset;    
    in float rotate;   
    in float zIdx;     // z index for zBuf clip only 
    in vec4 color;     // RGBA to color.a == 0.0 to remove not render
    in uint spriteIdx; 
    uniform vec4 sheetLayout[128];
    uniform vec2 sheetSize;     
    uniform mat2 view;              
    uniform vec2 origin;  
    out vec2 spr;
    out vec4 col;
    void main() {
        if (color.a <= alphaCut) { 
            gl_Position = vec4(-2); // put this instance outside clip
            return; 
        }
        col = color;
        vec4 sprite = sheetLayout[spriteIdx];
        spr = sprite.xy + verts * sprite.zw / sheetSize;
        vec2 loc = (verts - offset) * scale * sprite.zw;
        float xdx = cos(rotate);
        float xdy = sin(rotate);
        loc = view * (vec2(loc.x * xdx - loc.y * xdy, loc.x * xdy + loc.y * xdx) + pos - origin);
        gl_Position =  vec4(loc, zIdx, 1);
    }`;

const fragmentSrc = `#version 300 es
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D tex;
    #define alphaCut 0.0;
    in vec2 spr;
    in vec4 col;
    out vec4 pixel;
    void main() {
        pixel = texture(tex, spr) * col;
        if (pixel.a <= alphaCut) { discard; }
    }`;
```

Comment: I think you want `vec4(vec3(-2), 1)` or something do you not?

Comment: @gman I gave that a try and could not measure any performance difference to having `w = -2`. Why `w =1`?

Comment: @Blindman67 *"Why w =1"* - See the (deleted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the question's comments and the deleted answer, to move the vertex outside the clip space requires `gl_Position = vec4(vec3(-2), 1)`

Setting `gl_Position = vec4(-2)` will put the vertex at `vec3(1)` (top right on the near plane). This is inside the clip area and thus instance geom will end up in the fragment shader.

But why?

### Perspective division

When the vertex moves from the vertex shader as `gl_position` it is as a 4D vector. To clip the vertex we need a 3D vector that is outside 3d clip space.

The normalization of the vertex from 4D to 3D is called perspective division and is performed automatically by dividing the vectors `x`, `y` and `z` components by the `w` component.

Thus to correctly clip the geom instance and ensure it does not reach the fragment shader...

```
#define alphaCut 0.1
//...
void main() {
    if (color.a <= alphaCut) { 
        gl_Position = vec4(vec3(2), 1);
        return; 
    }
    //... rest of code
```